# New string added to drop down not displayed

Tags: angularjs

I have the below code in Angular for a drop down list. I need to add a new element/string to be displayed in the drop down.

This is the code.

```
search_reviews.js

$scope.addPhone = function () {
  $scope.reviewTypes.push({id: 1, description: 'Telephone'});
}

$scope.addOverPayment = function () {
  $scope.reviewTypes.push({id: 2, description: 'Overpayments'});
}

Have added a new element:

$scope.addWritten = function () {
  $scope.reviewTypes.push({id: 3, description: 'Written'});
}
```

in `search_reviews.html` have the code below to display the drop down on HTML page.

[image]

This new element ("Written") is displayed in the dropdown when application is run in localhost. But when the application is deployed on server as an EAR file, the new element is not displayed. No errors in build and deployment.

Any ideas please what could be the issue?

Thanks
R

Comment: there is troubleshooting information missing. Have you tried clearing the cache? Verifying that the code on the server matches what you have locally? If you push a new object onto a $scope array, it should reflect in the html. There must be a difference between the local and remote

Comment: Yes, we  cleared the cache. Tried different browsers. Also switched on the developer tools mode in browser to trace. No issue. We're now trying to check if that actual file is on the server where the app is running.